# Why TFS Build Step Extension Icon Is Missing?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I created a new extension for TFS following MS tutorial. For some reason when I'm adding Icon to my extension I can see this icon when I'm installing the extension and in the "Extension Manager" page,

But when I choose my extension **from the build step menu the image is missing**.

In the "vss-extension.json" file I added:

```
"icons": {
    "default": "images/icon.png"
}, 
"files": [
    {
        "path": "images",
        "addressable": true          
    },
    {
        "path": "dist",
        "addressable": true,
        "packagePath": "scripts"
    },
    {
        "path": "infoTab.html",
        "addressable": true
    },                   
    {
        "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib",
        "addressable": true,
        "packagePath": "lib"
    },    
    {
        "path": "buildtask"
    }       
],
```

The image file is 32x32

Should this image be reference in the "task.json" file as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The task itself has its own icon and it must be stored in the same directory as the `task.json` and must be called `icon.png` and be 32x32 pixels and optionally an additional `icon.svg` can be put alongside it. This has to do with the fact that one extension can contain multiple build tasks, each build task then has its own icon. It's not referenced from the task.json, the correct file name will cause it to be picked up.

For an example, check my [Azure Pipelines Snyk task](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-snyk-task/tree/master/snyk/v2). Also, if this is your complete extension manifest, then it's missing the Build task contribution point:

```
"contributions": [
{
  "id": "buildtask",
  "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
  "targets": [
    "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "buildtask"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I just got it worked before I read your answer, with the image named as "icon.png". Thanks for the reference anyway

Comment: I just tried to name it task.svg and this did not work when publishing the extension to Azure DevOps. I had to use icon.png as the other answer suggests

Comment: I supply both. I'm not sure whether the PNG is required, but the SVG is picked up when available alongside it.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is **not correct** for *Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server* version 15.105.25910.0.  Perhaps it was correct for previous versions.

1. The image file *must* be named **`icon.png`**.
2. The image file *must* be in the same folder as `task.json`.
3. The image file *should* be **32 x 32**; no image scaling is applied.

The `task.json` file does not contain any reference to this file.  It is located by using these conventions.

Comment: Is there an official documentation for that? Do you know the URL? Thanks!

Comment: I have not found any official documentation for this.  Some of this guidance is from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fb191da-ac32-40fa-b2ba-eecfecca6db5/why-tfs-build-step-extension-icon-is-missing .