# Azure DevOps custom extension icon missing

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, vsix

I have built an extension for Azure DevOps following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts

Then I upload it to Azure DevOps and share it only with my organization.

The problem is that when I open a build definition and click to add more tasks, the icon for my extension is missing:

[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8wi9.png)

I have followed the suggestions in the post below but nothing worked:

[Why TFS Build Step Extension Icon Is Missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050550/why-tfs-build-step-extension-icon-is-missing)

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide two files with icons, first one in your root folder and second one in the task folder. Also you should remember that icon should be 128x128 px or larger. Here you could see the example of your extension's folder structure:

- extensionManifest.json
- icon.png
- taskFolder

  - task.json
  - icon.png
  - index.js

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial does not mention that there also needs to be an icon named `icon.png` in the same folder as the `task.json` file.  Also make sure the icon is 32 x 32 px.  There is some documentation here: [Reference for integrating custom build tasks into extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/integrate-build-task?view=azure-devops)